# Unable to access RabbitMQ UI

Tags: kubernetes, rabbitmq

I deployed RabbitMQ in Kubernetes with the manifest below.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: rabbitmq
  namespace: X 
spec:
  serviceName: rabbitmq
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: rabbitmq
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: rabbitmq
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: rabbitmq
        image: rabbitmq:v01
        ports:
          - containerPort: 15672
            name: rabbitmq
          - containerPort: 5672
        env:
          - name: RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER
            value: "..."
          - name: RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS
            value: "..."
        livenessProbe:
          tcpSocket:
            port: 5672
          initialDelaySeconds: 30
          periodSeconds: 10
        readinessProbe:
          tcpSocket:
            port: 5672
          initialDelaySeconds: 10
          periodSeconds: 5
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: rabbitmq
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 5672
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 5672
  selector:
    app: rabbitmq
---
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
  name: rmq
  namespace: X
spec:
  entryPoints:
    - websecure
  routes:
  - match: Host(`Y`) 
    kind: Rule
    services:
    - name: rabbitmq
      port: 5672
  tls: {}
```

After applying this manifest I can see that my pod is running. But when I try to port forward I don't have access to RabbitMQ UI. I have the error 'internal server error' or 'bad gateway'.

In the logs of the pod I can see :

```
Server startup complete; 3 plugins started.
* rabbitmq_prometheus
* rabbitmq_web_dispatch
* rabbitmq_management_agent
```

In the logs I can see:

```
2023-06-05 21:23:36.319429+00:00 [info] <0.1006.0> accepting AMQP connection <0.1006.0> (IP1:34330 -> IP2:5672)
2023-06-05 21:23:36.319611+00:00 [error] <0.1006.0> closing AMQP connection <0.1006.0> (IP1:34330 -> IP2:5672):
2023-06-05 21:23:36.319611+00:00 [error] <0.1006.0> {bad_header,<<"GET / HT">>}
```

Where am I wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 issues with your manifests:

1. Your `Service` should be pointing to RabbitMQ's port `15672` for accessing UI as mentioned in this [document](https://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html) instead of `5672`.
2. Both `Service` and `StatefulSet` should be in same namespace. In your case they are in `default` and `x` respectively.

Comment: Thank you it works, I have to add manually "rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management", do you know how I can add this to the manifest ?

Comment: There are 2 options to achieve what you're asking: either create a custom RabbitMQ image which contains `rabbitmq_management` plugin or you can use official helm chart which allows you to enable any plugins on the run. Check out these 2 links (https://www.rabbitmq.com/kubernetes/operator/install-operator.html https://www.rabbitmq.com/kubernetes/operator/using-operator.html#create). First link explains how to install the chart and the 2nd one provides an example of creating a CRD for RabbitMQ based on the installed chart.